# Blackjack Program, No Idea Where to Start

Tags: java, blackjack

So I have a programming assignment to create a blackjack program. All I need to do is create the methods for it for the class BlackJackHand. Im pretty lost. Are my variables I have so far correct? Here is BlackJackHand:
package blackjack;

```
public class BlackjackHand {
    static final int MAX_HAND_SIZE = 5;
    public PlayingCard[] hand;
    public int numCards;
    private DeckOfCards[] deck;

    // an array of cards
    // number of cards in the hand
    // the deck this hand draws cards from

    // This constructor creates a new BlackjackHand using the provided deck.
    // Tip: Initialize all data fields, allocate space for the array of 5 cards,
    // then deal two cards from the deck into cards[0] and cards[1].
    // You'll have 2 cards in your hand, at this point.
    public BlackjackHand(DeckOfCards deck) {
     deck = new DeckOfCards();
   hand = new PlayingCard[5];  
   hand[0] = deck.dealACard();
   hand[1] = deck.dealACard();

    }

    // This method returns the point value of the hand.  It is a simple sum
    // of the PlayingCard values in the hand, except that an ace can count as
    // either 1 or 11 points.
    // Tip: Pretend the ace rule doesn;t exist, and sum up your card values.
    // If the sum is < 12, and there is an ace in the hand, then increment the
    // point value by 10 before returning it.
    public int valueOfHand() {

        return (0);
    }

    // Print out the names of all cards in the hand.
    // Tip: Don't iterate through all 5 cards, necessarily.  Use numCards
    // as the bound in your loop.
    public void printHand() {

    }

    // Return the number of cards in the hand.
    public int sizeOfHand() {
        return 0;
    }

    // Return the most recently dealt card in the hand.
    // Tip: That'll be the card at index numCards-1
    PlayingCard mostRecentCard() {
        return null;
    }

    // Draw a card from the deck.  If the hand already had 5 cards,
    // print out an error message instead.
    // Tip: Put the card from the deck into the array of cards at
    // index numCards, then increment numCards.
    public void hitMe() {
       if (numCards == 5){
           System.out.println("You already have 5 cards.");

       }//if
       else {

       }//else
    }//hitMe
```

Here is the class PlayingCards

```
package blackjack;

public class PlayingCard {
    private String suit; // "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts" or "spades"
    private int cardFace; // the value on the card. 1 for ace, 2 for 2, 13 for king, etc

    // constructor
    public PlayingCard(int v, String s) {
        cardFace = v;
        suit = s;
    }

    // Is this card an Ace?
    boolean isAce() {
        if(cardFace == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // return the blackjack point value of this card
    public int pointValue() {
       if(cardFace > 10) {
           return 10;
       } else {
           return cardFace;
       }
    }

    // make a string of the name of the card
    public String name() {
        String temp = "";

        // concatenate the String equivalent of cardFace to temp
        if(cardFace == 1) {
            temp += "Ace";
        } else if(cardFace == 11) {
            temp += "Jack";
        } else if(cardFace == 12) {
            temp += "Queen";
        } else if(cardFace == 13) {
            temp += "King";
        } else { // a number card
            temp += cardFace; // implcit type conversion of cardFace into String
        }

        // concatenate the name together
        temp = temp + " of " + suit;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Here is the class DeckOfCards:

package blackjack;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {

```
private PlayingCard[] cards;
private int topOfDeck; // array index that's "the top of the deck"

public DeckOfCards() {
    cards = new PlayingCard[52];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { // make all the "hearts" cards
        cards[i - 1] = new PlayingCard(i, "hearts");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { // make all the "hearts" cards
        cards[i - 1 + 13] = new PlayingCard(i, "clubs");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { // make all the "hearts" cards
        cards[i - 1 + 26] = new PlayingCard(i, "diamonds");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { // make all the "hearts" cards
        cards[i - 1 + 39] = new PlayingCard(i, "spades");
    }
    topOfDeck = 51;
}

public PlayingCard dealACard() {
    PlayingCard temp = cards[topOfDeck];
    topOfDeck--;
    return temp;
}

public void shuffle() {
    PlayingCard[] tempArray = new PlayingCard[52];

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = topOfDeck; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = r.nextInt(i + 1); // the index of a random card in the deck
        tempArray[i] = cards[index];
        // swap cards[i] with cards[index]
        PlayingCard tempCard = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[index];
        cards[index] = tempCard;
    }
    // at this point, tempArray has all the cards selected in random order
    cards = tempArray;
}
```

}

And finally the main class BlackJack:

```
package blackjack;

public class Blackjack {
    static final int WINNING_LIMIT = 21;
    static final int STAND_VALUE = 17;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards();
        deck.shuffle();

        // dealer's starting hand
        System.out.println("Let's play a hand of Blackjack!\nFirst, it's Dealer's turn.");
        BlackjackHand theDealer = new BlackjackHand(deck);
        System.out.println("Dealer begins with a hand of value " + theDealer.valueOfHand() + ":");
        theDealer.printHand();

        // dealer hits until he stands
        while (theDealer.valueOfHand() < STAND_VALUE) {
            if (theDealer.sizeOfHand() >= BlackjackHand.MAX_HAND_SIZE) { // 5 cards under 21: auto-win
                System.out.println("Dealer has drawn a hand of 5 cards, of value " + theDealer.valueOfHand() + ".  Automatic win!");
                theDealer.printHand();
                return;
            }
            theDealer.hitMe();
            System.out.println("Dealer draws a " + theDealer.mostRecentCard().name() + ", and now has " + theDealer.valueOfHand() + " points.");
        }

        // check to see if dealer busts
        if (theDealer.valueOfHand() > WINNING_LIMIT) {
            System.out.println("Dealer busts. Player 2 wins!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Dealer stands with a hand of value " + theDealer.valueOfHand() + ":");
        theDealer.printHand();

        // player 2's starting hand
        System.out.println("Now, it's player 2's turn.");
        BlackjackHand player2 = new BlackjackHand(deck);
        System.out.println("Player 2 begins with a hand of value " + player2.valueOfHand() + ":");
        player2.printHand();

        // player 2 hits until he stands.  Beat the dealer's hand, or bust.
        while (player2.valueOfHand() < theDealer.valueOfHand()) {
            if (player2.sizeOfHand() >= BlackjackHand.MAX_HAND_SIZE) { // 5 cards under 21: auto-win
                System.out.println("Player 2 has drawn a hand of 5 cards, of value " + player2.valueOfHand() + ".  Automatic win!");
                player2.printHand();
                return;
            }
            player2.hitMe();
            System.out.println("Player 2 draws a " + player2.mostRecentCard().name() + ", and now has " + player2.valueOfHand() + " points.");
        }

        // check to see if Player 2 busts
        if (player2.valueOfHand() > WINNING_LIMIT) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 busts. Dealer wins!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("The hand is over.");
        System.out.println("Dealer's hand has value " + theDealer.valueOfHand() + ":");
        theDealer.printHand();
        System.out.println("Player 2's hand has value " + player2.valueOfHand() + ":");
        player2.printHand();

        // figure out who won
        if (theDealer.valueOfHand() >= player2.valueOfHand()) {
            System.out.println("Dealer wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        }
    }//main
}//Blackjack
```

I know its daunting guys but I really need a little assistance. I dont want it done for me, I want to help understand it.

Comment: It looks like you have most of it there, keep going!

Comment: One thing right off the bat, your `private DeckOfCards[] deck;` should not be an array. You only want one deck of cards. Also, be more specific about what you want to understand. Anything in particular that confuses you?

Comment: what exactly is "cards" supposed to be? I understand the first two cards in the hand array are to be set to cards[0] and cards[1] how do initialize "cards"??

Comment: PlayingCard first = new PlayingCard(10, "D");

Answer (score 1):

```
public int valueOfHand() {


}
```

Start there.  How do you determine the value of a hand in black jack?  First, you determine the value of each card.  The PlayingCard class conveniently stores an integer value for each card. Create a variable called handsum, and add hand[0].cardFace to it.  Although, first you need to check if the value is 1, then add 10 more to handsum(per the instructions).  Then add the value of hand[0] to handsum, once again checking first if the value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use Enums for the suit and/or cardface.

I'm not sure if your `shuffle` method is random enough - I think you have a heavy bias towards swapping elements at the beginning of the array while the end of the array won't be randomized as much.  You can correct this by using an ArrayList for your deck instead of an array, or else by constructing a temporary ArrayList using `Arrays.asList`; create a temp ArrayList, then `remove` random elements from the original list and `add` them to the end of the temp list (`tempList.add(originalList.remove(r.nextInt(originalList.size())))`), finally copy the temp list back to an array (if you're still using an array for the deck) or else set `originalList = tempList` (if you're using an ArrayList for the deck).  Alternatively, you can use [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) instead of your custom shuffle method.

Comment: Yes, to removing the deck from the hand, but why recommend they use a *singleton*? That's a bit much when all they need is an instance of the deck held by the game object.

Comment: I have been givin only instructions to change the BlackjackHand class, and create the methods. The program is supposed to play a game itself, the user doesnt really do anything.

Comment: If there's only one BlackJackHand then no harm in keeping the deck where it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally start with the hitMe() function, where the other answer told you how to draw a card.  From there all you need to do is store in an array the dealers cards and separately the players cards.  From there you can easily get the size of the array(java keeps track of array size for you), as well as the most recent card (should be the most recently added card in array).  From there all you need to do is print the array and write valueOfHand().